# how to use std::copy for int**

Tags: c++

```
My2DClass::My2DClass(const int r, const int c, int mat[3][3]):m_r(r),m_c(c)
{
    matrix = new int*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_c; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    //std::copy(&mat[0][0], &mat[0][0] + m_r * m_c, &matrix[0][0]);
}
```

How to use `std::copy()` for `int**`? The commented line throws an exception at runtime.

Comment: The parameter you're passing to the contructor seems to always be `mat[3][3]`. What do the `r` and `c` parameters expect to accomplish, then? They are used to dynamically allocate a vector of pointers, and you seem to be attempting to copy `mat[3][3]` into the vector of pointers. Which only makes sense if both `r` and `c` are always `3`. What do you expect to accomplish when they're not?

Comment: The ideal solution would probably be to flatten your 2d matrix and do a single copy operation. The `matrix = new int*[r];` part seems out of place. Use a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: The `int mat[3][3]` parameter is really treated as just `int** mat`. So, even though the code *documents* that the dimensions are *expected* to be 3x3, the compiler does not *enforce* that in this case, so `r` and `c` *could* be other values.  If you really want to enforce 3x3, you would need to pass in the array by reference instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Actually I want to accept the parameter also as double pointer but for debugging purpose I have used mat[3][3].

Comment: @RemyLebeau `The int mat[3][3] parameter is really treated as just int** mat.` nope. It is adjusted to be `int(*)[3]`. The inner dimension cannot be other than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating an array of pointers to arrays, so a single call to `std::copy()` will not work. You would have to call `std::copy()` on every array individually.  So really, only your inner-most loop can be replaced with `std::copy()`, eg:

```cpp
My2DClass::My2DClass(const int r, const int c, int mat[3][3])
    : m_r(r), m_c(c)
{
    matrix = new int*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_r; i++) {
        std::copy(&mat[i][0], &mat[i][m_c], matrix[i]);
        // or: std::copy_n(&mat[i][0], m_c, matrix[i]);
    }
}
```

If you consolidate the 2 remaining loops into a single loop, eg:

```cpp
My2DClass::My2DClass(const int r, const int c, int mat[3][3])
    : m_r(r), m_c(c)
{
    matrix = new int*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new int[c];
        std::copy(&mat[i][0], &mat[i][c], matrix[i]);
        // or: std::copy_n(&mat[i][0], c, matrix[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you could replace that loop with `std::for_each()`, eg:

```cpp
My2DClass::My2DClass(const int r, const int c, int mat[3][3])
    : m_r(r), m_c(c)
{
    matrix = new int*[r];
    std::for_each(matrix, matrix + r,
        [=](int* &arr){
            arr = new int[c];
            std::copy(&mat[i][0], &mat[i][c], arr);
            // or: std::copy_n(&mat[i][0], c, arr);
        }
    );
}
```

Though, you really should avoid using `new[]` manually at all, consider using `std::vector` instead, which would greatly simplify management of your arrays, eg:

```cpp
// std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

My2DClass::My2DClass(const int r, const int c, int mat[3][3])
    : m_r(r), m_c(c), matrix(r)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        matrix[i].assign(&mat[i][0], &mat[i][c]);
    }
}
```

---

Otherwise, consider flattening your `matrix` into a single 1-dimensional array instead.  Especially since the input `mat` is a flat array in memory anyway. Then you can do a single `std::copy()` from one to the other, eg:

```cpp
// int *matrix;

My2DClass::My2DClass(const int r, const int c, int mat[3][3])
    : m_r(r), m_c(c), matrix(new int[r*c])
{
    std::copy(&mat[0][0], &mat[r][c], matrix);
}
```

Or, using `std::vector` instead:

```cpp
// std::vector<int> matrix;

My2DClass::My2DClass(const int r, const int c, int mat[3][3])
    : m_r(r), m_c(c), matrix(&mat[0][0], &mat[r][c])
{
}
```

Either way, you can convert 2-dimensional indexes into 1-dimensional indexes using this formula:

`(r * m_c) + c`

For example:

```cpp
int& My2DClass::operator()(int r, int c)
{
    return matrix[(r * m_c) + c];
}
```

Comment: And when `c` is more than 3, hillarity ensues.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau. It helps .Actually I was implementing a class having a double pointer as member variable.

Comment: @shrabanakumar I know, and that is not necessarily the best way to go.